# Laravel Livewire input fields not passing using postal code / address search api

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-livewire

In my laravel 10 with livewire ecommerce project, I am using postal code API to search and fill the address fields in the checkout page. Upon clicking to checkout after filling in the form, the validation process starts. Even though they have been filled using the API, the fields aren't recognized and gives message to fill them. Only after manually clicking the fields and type something out, the data is then validated.

API is called upon function `sample6_execDaumPostcode()`, and uses JavaScript to open a popup page where user can search for their address, and afterwards the fields are automatically inserted.

Here is my livewire checkout component =

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Frontend\Checkout;

use App\Models\Cart;
use App\Models\Order;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Orderitem;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class CheckoutShow extends Component
{
    public $carts, $totalProductAmount = 0;

    public $fullname, $email, $phone, $pincode, $address, $secondAddress, $thirdAddress, $payment_mode = NULL, $payment_id = NULL;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'fullname' => 'required|string|max:121',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:121',
            'phone' => 'required|string|max:11|min:9',
            'pincode' => 'required|string|max:5|min:5',
            'address' => 'required|string|max:500',
            'secondAddress' => 'required|string|max:500',
            'thirdAddress' => 'nullable|string|max:500'
        ];
    }
```

Here is the livewire page view input fields =

```
 <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <label>우편번호</label>
        <input type="text" wire:model="pincode" class="form-control" id="sample6_postcode" placeholder="우편번호">
        @error('pincode') <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small> @enderror
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input class="btn btn1" type="button" onclick="sample6_execDaumPostcode()" value="우편번호 찾기">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
        <label>주소</label>
        <textarea type="text" wire:model="address" class="form-control" id="sample6_address" placeholder="주소" rows="2"></textarea>
        @error('address') <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small> @enderror
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
        <label>상세주소</label>
        <input type="text" wire:model="secondAddress" class="form-control" id="sample6_detailAddress" placeholder="상세주소">
        @error('secondAddress') <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small> @enderror
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
        <label>참고항목</label>
        <input type="text" wire:model="thirdAddress" class="form-control" id="sample6_extraAddress" placeholder="참고항목">
    </div>
```

Daum javascript

```
<script>
    function sample6_execDaumPostcode() {
        new daum.Postcode({
            oncomplete: function(data) {

                // 팝업에서 검색결과 항목을 클릭했을때 실행할 코드를 작성하는 부분.

                const component = Livewire.getByName("checkout-show")[0];

                // 각 주소의 노출 규칙에 따라 주소를 조합한다.
                // 내려오는 변수가 값이 없는 경우엔 공백('')값을 가지므로, 이를 참고하여 분기 한다.
                var addr = ''; // 주소 변수
                var extraAddr = ''; // 참고항목 변수

                //사용자가 선택한 주소 타입에 따라 해당 주소 값을 가져온다.
                if (data.userSelectedType === 'R') { // 사용자가 도로명 주소를 선택했을 경우
                    addr = data.roadAddress;
                } else { // 사용자가 지번 주소를 선택했을 경우(J)
                    addr = data.jibunAddress;
                }

                // 사용자가 선택한 주소가 도로명 타입일때 참고항목을 조합한다.
                if(data.userSelectedType === 'R'){
                    // 법정동명이 있을 경우 추가한다. (법정리는 제외)
                    // 법정동의 경우 마지막 문자가 "동/로/가"로 끝난다.
                    if(data.bname !== '' && /[동|로|가]$/g.test(data.bname)){
                        extraAddr += data.bname;
                    }
                    // 건물명이 있고, 공동주택일 경우 추가한다.
                    if(data.buildingName !== '' && data.apartment === 'Y'){
                        extraAddr += (extraAddr !== '' ? ', ' + data.buildingName : data.buildingName);
                    }
                    // 표시할 참고항목이 있을 경우, 괄호까지 추가한 최종 문자열을 만든다.
                    if(extraAddr !== ''){
                        extraAddr = ' (' + extraAddr + ')';
                    }
                    // 조합된 참고항목을 해당 필드에 넣는다.
                    //document.getElementById("sample6_extraAddress").value = extraAddr;
                    component.$set("thirdAddress", extraAddr);

                } else {
                    //document.getElementById("sample6_extraAddress").value = '';
                    component.$set("thirdAddress", '');
                }

                // 우편번호와 주소 정보를 해당 필드에 넣는다.
                //document.getElementById('sample6_postcode').value = data.zonecode;
                component.$set("pincode", data.zonecode);
                //document.getElementById("sample6_address").value = addr;
                component.$set("address", addr);
                // 커서를 상세주소 필드로 이동한다.
                //document.getElementById("sample6_detailAddress").focus();

            }
        }).open();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It would be good to see how *sample6_execDaumPostcode()* updates fields. 
Generally speaking you need to update the public properties of the *CheckoutShow* class, not the DOM elements

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to integrate the *sample6_execDaumPostcode()* function into an Alpine object, however to avoid messing up your code too much you could try this:

```js
function sample6_execDaumPostcode() {

   new daum.Postcode({

      oncomplete: function(data) {

         const component = Livewire.getByName("checkout-show")[0];

         // .....
    
         //instead of:
         //document.getElementById("sample6_address").value = addr;
    
         //use this (the wire:model argument is the identifier): 
         component.$set("address", addr, false);

        // the same for each assignment
      
        // ..... 
}
```

I added the *false* parameter to the *$set* magic method to prevent live updating, assuming the fields will be sent on form submission
I've also assumed that the component blade name is *checkout-show*, if not you must update the *Livewire.getByName()* instruction

Comment: i have tried your codes, after searching for the address in the api, the fields wont fill in. The popup page does not close. (Not form submission)

Comment: Evidently there is some error. Have you checked the browser console?

Comment: Error message = Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$set'). You can see the script in my question again p.s Sorry for late reply

Comment: I suspect that the Livewire object is out of scope in the *sample6_execDaumPostcode()* function. Try adding a `console.log (Livewire.getByName("checkout-show"), windows.Livewire.getByName("checkout-show"));` to see the result. It would be useful to know how *sample6_execDaumPostcode()* is included

Comment: checkout:374 Uncaught ReferenceError: windows is not defined
    at sample6_execDaumPostcode (checkout:374:59)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (checkout:220:153) p.s my apologies for late reply again, i assume time difference

Comment: Sorry, it had to be *window*, not *windows*

Comment: it is showing the same console log message as before

Comment: It seems unlikely to me

Comment: Is placing the console log right under function sample6_execDaumPostcode()  and before new daum.Postcode({ correct?

Comment: Yes. Please report the full error message

Comment: Array [] then this --> checkout:415 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$set')
    at Object.oncomplete (checkout:415:31)
    at postcode.v2.js:1:18130

Comment: []
length
: 
0
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
at
: 
ƒ at()
concat
: 
ƒ concat()
constructor
: 
ƒ Array()
copyWithin
: 
ƒ copyWithin()
entries
: 
ƒ entries()
every
: 
ƒ every()
fill
: 
ƒ fill()
length
: 
1
name
: 
"fill"
arguments
: 
(...)
caller
: 
(...)
[[Prototype]]
: 
ƒ ()
[[Scopes]]
: 
Scopes[0]
filter
: 
ƒ filter()
find
: 
ƒ find()
findIndex
: 
ƒ findIndex()
findLast
: 
ƒ findLast(

Comment: That seems the output of the error, not the *console.log()*. We must understand why your *sample6_execDaumPostcode()* can't reference the Livewire object: how do you include this function in the page?

Comment: i have directly added the script in the livewire blade. used @push('scripts) to call the the script from app.blade.php =  <!-- Daum 주소 API Script -->
    <script src="//t1.daumcdn.net/mapjsapi/bundle/postcode/prod/postcode.v2.js"></script>

    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/script.js') }}"></script>
    @yield('script')

    @livewireScripts
    @stack('scripts'). I have tried placing function sample6_execDaumPostcode() in the app.blade.php to see if problem gets solved, but its the same.

Comment: there are no other errors in Console (devtools)